# VB.NET Get Local Computer Name

Tags: vb.net, hostname

I need to retrieve the local (not server) machine name on an intranet web application. After a lot of searching, it looks like the below should work...

```
Dim Name As String = (Dns.GetHostEntry(Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_HOST")).HostName)
```

However, this returns the error "No such host is known". Any ideas where I'm going wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Is `Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_HOST")` giving you the expected value? If so, does the DNS server that the web server uses know how to resolve it?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.machinename?view=net-6.0

Comment: Hans - This will give the sever name not the machine name

Comment: Andrew - Yes, I get the expected IP address with Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_HOST"). I can also ping this IP by machine name from command prompt on the server, so not sure why it can't resolve. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your statement isn't working but I use

```
Dim Hostname as string = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
```

which you may fine useful.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this will give me the server name only, not the local  machine

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this wasn't working because we didn't have reverse lookup configured on our DNS. Since configuring this, it's now working as intended